# Is there a library that can handle LIDAR data in Windows Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, lidar, liblas

I'm looking for a library that can manipulate .liblas data in windows. I'm using windows 10, and my anaconda python version is 3.7. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *.liblas data* you mean the **ASPRS LAS** file format, you can use [laspy](https://pypi.org/project/laspy/).